# how do I enable debug logging in php5-ldap

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, nginx, php5

I have phabricator running on Ubuntu behind nginx and php5-fpm, and now trying to figure out why ldap logins fail.

Is there a way to enable verbose logging of the php-ldap code? What file is the log printed to?

Comment: did yuh find a way to do this i get invalid credentials

Comment: I used wireshark to inspect ldap traffic and I think that helped me find a problem in my config